# how to check if pigpio is already initialised?

Tags: pigpio

I would like to check if pigpio has already been initialized, is there a way i can check this at run time?

Currently what i am doing is declaring a bool flag that is set after gpioInitialise(). Although thats fine and good, i would like to know if the library already has way for me to check ?

```
bool initialiseFlag = 0;

int main(){

if(gpioInitialize<0)
initialiseFlag = 1;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

gpioInitialise() is defined as follows.

```c
int gpioInitialise(void)
{
   int status;

   if (libInitialised) return PIGPIO_VERSION;

   DBG(DBG_STARTUP, "not initialised, initialising");

   runState = PI_STARTING;

   status = initInitialise();

   if (status < 0)
   {
      runState = PI_ENDING;
      initReleaseResources();
   }
   else
   {
      libInitialised = 1;

      runState = PI_RUNNING;

      if (!(gpioCfg.ifFlags & PI_DISABLE_ALERT))
      {
         while (pthAlertRunning != PI_THREAD_RUNNING) myGpioDelay(1000);
      }

   }

   return status;
}
```

Internally it uses a flag libInitialised.  That is not accessible to your program.  So doing what you are (almost) doing is the best way.

I suggest

```c
if (gpioInitialise() >= 0)
   pigpioInitialised = 1;
else
   pigpioInitialised = 0;
```